# Updating component while only rendering once (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I need help on how I can get the markersList to populate with the Google Maps markers without it rendering twice at start. In the initMap method, the loop is pushing markers into the markersList in the component's state. Which is what I think is causing it to render twice when the page initializes.  I tried ComponentWillMount but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

```
   class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      map: "",
      markersList: [],
      locations: [
        {
          title: "Powell's Books",
          address: "1005 W Burnside St, Portland, OR 97209",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.523096,
            lng: -122.681354
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Ground Kontrol",
          address: "511 NW Couch St, Portland, OR 97209",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.523943,
            lng: -122.675872
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Portland Art Museum",
          address: "1219 SW Park Ave, Portland, OR 97205",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.51615,
            lng: -122.683357
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Roseland Theater",
          address: "8 NW 6th Ave, Portland, OR 97209",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.52328,
            lng: -122.676297
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Voodoo Doughnuts",
          address: "22 SW 3rd Ave, Portland, OR 97204",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.522713,
            lng: -122.672944
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Arlene Schnitzer Concert Hall",
          address: "1037 SW Broadway, Portland, OR 97205",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.517197,
            lng: -122.681419
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Pioneer Place",
          address: "700 SW 5th Ave, Portland, OR 97204",
          coordinates: {
            lat: 45.518335,
            lng: -122.677261
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    let infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow();
    let locations = this.state.locations;
    let bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    let tempArray = [];
    let listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("list-item")

    for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      let wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&origin=*&search=" + this.state.locations[i].title + "&format=json";

      let newMarker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        map: newMap,
        position: locations[i].coordinates,
        title: locations[i].title,
        animation: window.google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        id: i
      });
      tempArray.push(newMarker);
      bounds.extend(newMarker.position);

      newMarker.addListener("click", function () {
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
        newMap.panTo(newMarker.position);
        axios.get(wikiUrl)
          .then(response => {
            const wikiInfo = response.data;
            infoWindow.setContent(`<p><strong>${wikiInfo[0]}</strong><br>${locations[i].address}</p><p>${wikiInfo[2][0]}</p><p>Click <a href='${wikiInfo[3][0]}' target='_blank'><strong>HERE</strong></a> for more information on ${wikiInfo[0]}.</p>`)
          })
      })

    }
    this.setState({
      markersList: tempArray
    })
    newMap.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  filterList = (event) => {
    let keyword = event.target.value;
    let filtered = this.state.markersList.filter(item => {

      return item.title.indexOf(keyword) > -1
    });
    this.setState({
      markersList: filtered
    })

  }
  initMap = () => {
    const map = document.querySelector(".map");

    let newMap = new window.google.maps.Map(map, {
      center: {
        lat: 45.519692,
        lng: -122.680496,
        mapTypeControl: false
      },
      zoom: 16
    });
    this.setState({
      map: newMap
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <div className="menu">
          <SearchInput
            change={this.filterList}
          />

          <ul className="location-list" >
            {

              this.state.markersList.map((marker, index) => {
                return <ListItem
                key={index}
                title={marker.title}
                />
              })
            }

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="map">

        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ComponentWillMount should solve your problem.It will not cause your component to render twice as setState inside willMount will not cause additional rerenders

Comment: ComponentWillMount didn't work, unless I was doing it wrong. Basically, I want the markersList populated in time for the first render.

Comment: can u share ur willMount Logic?

Comment: If your markers list is a constant, it shouldn't be on the state. Then you'd just use the constant on the first render.

Comment: No, the markers list is not meant to be a constant. Because I want to be able to manipulate the array data as part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shouldComponentUpdate` to decide if the component should re-render.

You could keep the map in a child component and send locations through props in which case you'll need to check for props instead of state.
`nextProps.locations !== this.props.locations`